# How do you modify an SQL query to iteratate over every 100 results and then perform an outter query?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, query-optimization

The following query:

```
DELETE FROM attachmentdata
WHERE attachmentid IN
  ( SELECT attachmentid
    FROM attachments
    WHERE pageid IN
      ( SELECT contentid FROM content_delete )
  );
```

works perfectly if the inner nested SELECT query returns a small list (maybe couple hundred).

But now I"m trying to run it on something that will return 10000 - 15000 rows and this is taking a long time.  I ran the query and after 45 minutes nothing happened.

Is it possible to modify the query so that every 100 results that are returned by the inner SELECT it goes to the outer DELETE query and then moves on to the next 100 results?

Comment: In general, you have to do this in a scripting language outside the raw SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - It's ok if the solution uses shell / bash scripting.

Comment: @user1068636 . . . In Oracle, it would be PL/SQL scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it a lot faster, get rid of the `IN`s ...

(oracle)...

```
DELETE  ad
FROM attachmentdata AS ad 
INNER JOIN attachments AS att ON ad.attachmentid = att.attachmentid
INNER JOIN content_delete AS cd ON cd.contentid = att.pageid
```

(mysql) ...

```
DELETE  ad.*
FROM attachmentdata AS ad 
INNER JOIN attachments AS att ON ad.attachmentid = att.attachmentid
INNER JOIN content_delete AS cd ON cd.contentid = att.pageid
```